# How to add transition to div border

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following code :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#add").click(function(){
    $("#content").append("<p>New text</p>");
  });
});
```

```css
#content{
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<p>TEXT</p>
</div>
<button id="add">Add text</button>
```

I expect when I click on the button add, the content div will have a transition when he expand.
I have tried with the following animation css :

```
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease;
transition: all .5s ease;
```

I would like to add a transition to the div

I also tried with `.show('slow');`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the border...you're changing the height of the div and you can't transition to/from `auto`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using another element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function initBorder() {
    $("#content-border").css({
      height: $("#content").outerHeight(),
      width: $("#content").outerWidth(),
    });
  }

  initBorder();

  $("#add").click(function() {
    $("#content").append("<p>New text</p>");
    initBorder();
  });
});
```

```css
#content {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

#content-border {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <p>TEXT</p>
  <div id="content-border"></div>
</div>

<button id="add">Add text</button>
```

We can use the fade function for a smoother transition.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function initBorder() {
    $("#content-border").css({
      height: $("#content").outerHeight(),
      width: $("#content").outerWidth(),
    });
  }

  initBorder();

  $("#add").click(function() {
    $("#content").append("<p>New text</p>");
    $("#content").find("p").last().fadeOut(0).fadeIn(500);
    initBorder();
  });
});
```

```css
#content {
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

#content-border {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <p>TEXT</p>
  <div id="content-border"></div>
</div>

<button id="add">Add text</button>
```